# Doubts in Joins - MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I have a query,

```
SELECT E.staffid AS staff
SUM(E.Frequency='Less') AS lessCount, 
SUM(E.Frequency='More') AS moreCount,  
FROM effort_frequency E 
INNER JOIN ost_staff S ON S.staff_id = E.staffid 
WHERE E.log_date BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-05-23' 
GROUP BY E.staffid
```

I get the below table,

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| Staff | lessCount | moreCount |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  1    |    2      |     3     |
|  3    |    1      |     4     |
|  5    |    2      |     3     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

You can see that the 2 & 4 is missing in the result, There will be *no rows* with staff_id 2 & 4 in the `effort_frequency` table for the given date, but I'm trying to join the `ost_staff` table, so that I can get something like the below table, The ost_staff will contain all the staff id, lets say 1-5.

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| Staff | lessCount | moreCount |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  1    |    2      |     3     |
|  2    |    0      |     0     |
|  3    |    1      |     4     |
|  4    |    0      |     0     |
|  5    |    2      |     3     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

I tried outer joins but its not working, I think I'm making mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `WHERE` clause to `ON` clause, and change the `INNER JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`. And change the `GROUP BY E.staffid` to `GROUP BY S.staff_id`; likewise with `SELECT E.staffid,` change it to `SELECT s.staff_id`:

```
SELECT S.staff_id AS staff

    COALESCE(SUM(E.Frequency='Less'),0) AS lessCount, 
    COALESCE(SUM(E.Frequency='More'),0) AS moreCount,  

FROM effort_frequency E 

RIGHT JOIN ost_staff S 
ON S.staff_id = E.staffid 
AND E.log_date BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-05-23' 

GROUP BY S.staff_id
```

If you want to use `LEFT JOIN`, switch the tables ost_staff and effort_frequency:

```
SELECT S.staff_id AS staff

    COALESCE(SUM(E.Frequency='Less'),0) AS lessCount, 
    COALESCE(SUM(E.Frequency='More'),0) AS moreCount,  

FROM ost_staff S 

LEFT JOIN effort_frequency E 
ON S.staff_id = E.staffid 
AND E.log_date BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-05-23' 

GROUP BY s.staff_id
```

You can also use IFNULL in lieu of COALESCE. IFNULL works only on MySQL though

Answer (score 1):

Did you try **[LEFT JOIN](http://mysqljoin.com/joins/left-outer-join-tutorial/)** ?

```
SELECT E.staffid AS staff
       COALESCE(SUM(E.Frequency='Less'),0) AS lessCount, 
       COALESCE(SUM(E.Frequency='More'),0) AS moreCount,  
FROM effort_frequency E LEFT JOIN ost_staff S 
      ON S.staff_id = E.staffid 
WHERE E.log_date BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-05-23' 
GROUP BY E.staffid
```

[**Article to Learn SQL JOINS**](http://mysqljoin.com/)

**[COALESCE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)** was added because it will return *NULL* value if there are no records exist.

Comment: Your's also very helpful, I tried Right Join & it worked. Thanks A Lot  :)